# xslt from two xml files using a matching node value

Tags: xslt-1.0

Kindly help me with the below expected output.I tried doing using for-each etc but ParentUUID1 is getting repeated for all RECORDS. I need to match the subscription_id key attribute from File2.xml with that in MainInput.xml and get the final expected output.

### MainInput.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<qw:ACCOUNT_CHANGES xmlns:qw="http://xmlns.dummy.com/qwSubsResponse">
  <qw:RECORD>
    <qw:SUBSCRIPTION>
      <qw:INFO key="subscriptionid_hash">abcd</qw:INFO>
      <qw:INFO key="subscription_id">140172</qw:INFO>
      <qw:INFO key="uuid">ParentUUID1</qw:INFO>
    </qw:SUBSCRIPTION>
    <qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
      <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
    <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
    </qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
    <qw:Platform>plat1</qw:Platform>
    <qw:skip_subscription>1</qw:skip_subscription>
  </qw:RECORD>
  <qw:RECORD>
    <qw:SUBSCRIPTION>
      <qw:INFO key="subscriptionid_hash">xyz</qw:INFO>
      <qw:INFO key="subscription_id">140</qw:INFO>
      <qw:INFO key="uuid">ParentUUID2</qw:INFO>
    </qw:SUBSCRIPTION>
    <qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
      <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidrcd2</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
    </qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
    <qw:Platform>plat1</qw:Platform>
    <qw:skip_subscription>1</qw:skip_subscription>
  </qw:RECORD>
</qw:ACCOUNT_CHANGES>
```

### File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<qw:ACCOUNT_CHANGES xmlns:qw="http://xmlns.dummy.com/qwSubsResponse">
  <qw:RECORD>
    <qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
      <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
    <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>      
    </qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
    <qw:Platform>plat1</qw:Platform>
    <qw:skip_subscription>1</qw:skip_subscription>
  </qw:RECORD>
  <qw:RECORD>
    <qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
      <qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
        <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id">140</qw:FODATA>
        <qw:FODATA key="uuid">uuidrcd2</qw:FODATA>
      </qw:FO_ACCOUNT>
    </qw:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
    <qw:Platform>plat1</qw:Platform>
    <qw:skip_subscription>1</qw:skip_subscription>
  </qw:RECORD>
</qw:ACCOUNT_CHANGES>
```

### Expected output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns1:ACCOUNT_CHANGES xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.dummy.com/qwSubsResponse">
   <ns1:RECORD>
      <ns1:SUBSCRIPTION>
         <ns1:INFO key="uuid">ParentUUID1</qw:INFO>
      </ns1:SUBSCRIPTION>
      <ns1:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
         <ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
            <ns1:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</ns1:FODATA>
            <ns1:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</ns1:FODATA>
         </ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
         <ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
            <ns1:FODATA key="subscription_id">140172</ns1:FODATA>
            <ns1:FODATA key="uuid">uuidfouser1</ns1:FODATA>
         </ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
      </ns1:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
   </ns1:RECORD>
   <ns1:RECORD>
      <ns1:SUBSCRIPTION>
         <ns1:INFO key="uuid">ParentUUID2</qw:INFO>
      </ns1:SUBSCRIPTION>
      <ns1:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
         <ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
            <ns1:FODATA key="subscription_id">140</ns1:FODATA>
            <ns1:FODATA key="uuid">uuidrcd2</ns1:FODATA>
         </ns1:FO_ACCOUNT>
      </ns1:ALL_FO_ACCOUNTS>
   </ns1:RECORD>
</ns1:ACCOUNT_CHANGES>
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of the required transformation in a few words. Simplifying the example would also help.

Comment: I need to create a subscription node (refer expected output for reach Record)  by matching <qw:FODATA key="subscription_id"> Node value from File2.xml with that of  <qw:INFO key="subscription_id"> Node value in MainInput.xml. 

All <ns1:FODATA key="subscription_id"> Node values for each Record will be same (Refer File2.xml), since they belong to a same subscription record.

Comment: Sorry, I still find it too confusing. Please edit your question and indicate clearly the source of each value in the output.